# cannot retrieve all count under child

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

This is logical error, I am retrieving `7` **children count** under `stocks` but the output only four **children count**

`OUTPUT: "4 Rubber Duck"`

I use `textView.setText(allDuck " Rubber Duck");` and the Output not all Rubber Duck. It should total `7` output not four. This is the data structure and code in problem but I don't know where the problem is, could you please help me find the logical error: I think, firebase confuse to read my uid,

```
Database
    DuckCompany
       SALES
          WireHouse
             Inventory
                  RubberDUCK
                     DuckID
                        axRGznal3nkhxsDax // this is uid
                                stocks
                                   -LEeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee  // this is id 
                                                redValue:"71"
                                   -LFffffffffffffffff 
                                                redValue:"71"
                                   -LGggggggggggggggg 
                                                redValue:"71"
                        cpsGGGGNxQQQOWqh
                                stocks 
                                   -LAaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
                                                redValue:"71"
                                   -LBbbbbbbbbbbbbbb 
                                                redValue:"71"
                                   -LCccccccccccccc 
                                                redValue:"71"
                                   -LDddddddddddddd
                                                redValue:"71"
```

.

```
ref
   .child("DuckCompany")
   .child("SALES")
   .child("WireHouse")
   .child("Inventory")
   .child("RubberDUCK") 
   .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
       for (DataSnapshot uids : dataSnapshot.child("DuckID").getChildren()) {

          uidKeys = uids.getKey();

          if (uidKeys != null) {
             int allDuck = (int) dataSnapshot.child("DuckID").child(uidKeys).child("stocks").getChildrenCount();                            
          }
       }
       textView.setText(allDuck " Rubber Duck");

    }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over all (2) keys under `DuckID` and getting the amount of children under `stock` for each of them, but you're not adding those amounts anywhere, you just overwrite the previous value.

Try this instead:

```
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        int allDuck = 0;

        for (DataSnapshot uids : dataSnapshot.child("DuckID").getChildren()) {

            String uidKeys = uids.getKey();

            if (uidKeys != null) {
                allDuck += (int) dataSnapshot.child("DuckID").child(uidKeys).child("stocks").getChildrenCount();                            
            }
        }
        textView.setText(allDuck " Rubber Duck");
    }
```

Comment: i will try your code, and come back again. thanks for your respon : - )